# Adding column depending on another column of a list object

Tags: r

I have a list object in R

```
 dl <- list(matrix(c(1,5,.2,.7), nrow=2,dimnames=list(c(),c("x","y"))), matrix(c(0,1,.01,.4), nrow=2,dimnames=list(c(),c("x","y") )))
```

I want to add another column `z <- rbinom(2,1,y)` with each element of the list. That is `z` is a bernoulli random variable with probability vector `y` of each list. So far I did:

```
a=dl[[1]]
a=data.frame(a)
a$z <- with(a, rbinom(2,1,y))

b=dl[[2]]
b=data.frame(b)
b$z <- with(b, rbinom(2,1,y))
```

But this coding looks messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
> lapply(dl,FUN=function(mat) z <- cbind(mat,rbinom(2,1,mat[,2])))
[[1]]
     x   y  
[1,] 1 0.2 0
[2,] 5 0.7 0

[[2]]
     x    y  
[1,] 0 0.01 0
[2,] 1 0.40 1
```

Comment: Yes, but is there any way to add the column name as `z`?

Comment: Probably, you need `lapply(dl,FUN=function(mat) cbind(mat, z = rbinom(2,1,mat[,2])))`

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you very much.